# Merge large number of spark dataframes into one

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdfs

I'm querying a cached hive temp table using different queries satisfying different conditions over more than 1500 times inside a for loop. I need to merge them all using unionAll inside the loop. But I get stackoverflow error due to the fact that spark cannot keep up with the RDD lineage.

pseudo code:

```
df=[from a hive table]
tableA=[from a hive table]
tableA.registerTempTable("tableA")
HiveContext.sql('CACHE TABLE tableA')

for i in range(0,2000):
    if (list[0]['column1']=='xyz'):
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    elif ():
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    elif ():
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    elif ():
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    else:
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
```

This throws StackOverFlow error due to RDD lineage becoming hard. So I tried checkpointing as follows:

```
for i in range(0,2000):
    if (list[0]['column1']=='xyz'):
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    elif ():
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    else:
        df1=query something from tableA
        df=df.unionAll(df1)
    df.rdd.checkpoint
    df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
```

I got the same error. So I tried SaveAsTable which I always wanted to avoid because of lag in job submission between each hql queries and hive io inside a loop. But this approach worked well.

```
for i in range(0,2000):
    if (list[0]['column1']=='xyz'):
        df=query something from tableA
        df.write.saveAsTable('output', mode='append')
    elif ():
        df=query something from tableA
        df.write.saveAsTable('output', mode='append')
```

I need help in avoiding saving the dataframe into hive inside the loop. I want to merge the dfs in some manner that's in-memory and efficient. One of the other options I tried is to insert the query result directly into a temp table for which I get a error: cannot insert into a RDD based table.

Comment: In general this kind of looping and union operations are always going to result in problems in Spark. What sort of queries are you running? Perhaps there is a more clever way to refactor your code, which doesn't require looping. Also, what are the conditions?

Comment: Conditions are not complex ones - some regexes matching and some direct integer matching. But the thing is that I've enabled the end users to create these conditions who can only write sql based ones and import them into spark to process the data. In naive terms, my application works like a sql workbench - difference being it runs all the queries and stores the result in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

maybe, temp table for result will work.

```
df1="query something from tableA".registerTempTable("result")
sqlContext.sql("Insert into result query something from tableA")
```

Comment: like I mentioned in the post, it throws an error: can't insert into RDD based table.